# How to locate a file from user provided input in Java

Tags: java, file

I've got a program which reads in multiple json files and then does some analysis of the information contained in those files.

My project structure is laid out like :

```
    /main
        /java
        /resources
            /data
                file1.json
                file2.json
                ...
                fileN.json
```

I'm attempting to give the user the ability to specify an alternate location if they have a different data set they want to analyze.

I'm using the following code to create an array of File objects:

```
 ClassLoader loader = myClass.class.getClassLoader();
 URL url = loader.getResource(location);
 try {
     String path = url.getPath();
     return new File(path).listFiles();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
     throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

Note: I'm using myClass.class.getClassLoader() because I'm calling from a static method rather than from an instantiated object.

This works successfully when the `location = "data"`. However if I pass in an absolute path to a different location (ex: `location = "/Users/myuser/Desktop/data"`) that has the same data files in it I'm getting a NPE.

Is there a good way that will allow me to use the src/main/resources directory by default but allow my user to specify an absolute path to the data if they choose?

Comment: How about `java.io.File(location).isAbsolute()`?

Comment: Perhaps use something like this: `URL = url; if (whateverCondition) { url = 
new File(thesuppliedOrSelectedFilePath).toURI().toURL(); } else { url = loader.getResource(location); }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassLoader loader = myClass.class.getClassLoader();
URL url = loader.getResource(location);
```

The code above only works with files that exist in your class path.
Thus you can change it to read from src/main/resources directory by default and the absolute path given by the user by updating it to this:

```
try {
     return new File(location).listFiles();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
     throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

```
        ClassLoader cl = myClass.class.getClassLoader();
        URL url = cl.getResource(location);
        if (url == null) {
            //the location does not exist in class path
            return new File(location).listFiles();
        } else {
            return new File(url.getPath()).listFiles();
        }
```

But I think that the better way is:

```
    private File[] readFile(String userLocation) {
        if(userLocation == null || userLocation.isEmpty()) {
            // user do not specify the path
            return new File(myClass.class.getResource("data").getPath()).listFiles();
        } else {
            return new File(userLocation).listFiles();
        }
    }
```